# How to get OTG files via Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, usb-otg, storage-access-framework

So, I want to read a very specific file from any connected USB OTG drive. It's a text file that should be stored on a USB stick and I need to read that file, which has a specific name, say `myFile.txt`. While I understand this kind of getting user input is dumb and not user-friendly, it's what I'm told to implement.

But my problem is, that there are many mount points for USB Drives. on my phone it's `/storage/USBStorage1`, while on my friend's it's `/storage/[HEX_ID]`. I tried to get all of them, but it's not possible. in Nexus phones it mounts on `/mnt/media_rw/[HEX_ID]` which requires root access.

I searched around a little and found SAF, but I didn't find anything on how to use it to open any file without user's direct selection. I don't want the picker to show up. I just want to check if `[USB_OTG_PATH]/myFile.txt` exists or not, and if it exists I want to read it.

And on a sidenote, do I need to have root acces to read `/mnt` folders (except `media_rw`)?

Comment: On modern systems it will be one of the `File` objects delivered by getExternalFilesDirs()`[.

Comment: @greenapps: Only if the file happens to be in one of those directories. The OP seems to want this file to be at an arbitrary location.

Comment: @CommonsWare: From that File object OP can derive the root of the drive. From there on he adds his path. The root is the part before `/Android/`.

Comment: @greenapps: At which point, he starts getting `EACCESS` and related errors. Apps have read/write access to the *specific* directories returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()` and kin, but cannot navigate outside of them.

Comment: @CommonsWare: OP will have requested all necessary permissions already. Like READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: @greenapps: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is for external storage. External storage is not removable storage, and the OP is interested in removable storage. `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` has no impact on USB OTG devices.

Comment: @CommansWare: Ok. Thanks.  But i have never seen an Android device where i could not read the whole OTG disk. Writing indeed is another story.

Comment: @CommonsWare: As far as i know READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is certainly needed for a micro SD card.

Comment: @greenapps: No, it's not in `getExternalFilesDirs()`. That returns the directory of files stored on External Storage. What I want is something named `getRemovableStorageDirs()` that returns the directory of mounted USB sticks.

Comment: You are aware of the TWO functions? `getExternalFilesDir()` and `getExternalFilesDirs()`? Use the latter. And you should have mentioned the Android version of course if it did not work.

Comment: `but I didn't find anything on how to use it to open any file without user's direct selection.`. You only once have to let the user choose the root of that usb drive. After that your app can read the whole -same- drive for the lifetime of your app without user intervention.

Comment: And for Android 7 StorageManager and StorageVolumes can be used.

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't find anything on how to use it to open any file without user's direct selection

That is because there is no option for this.

> I just want to check if [USB_OTG_PATH]/myFile.txt exists or not, and if it exists I want to read it.

That is not supported.

*If* your file is located in one of the directories returned by `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()`, *then* you can access it directly using normal Java file I/O. However, AFAIK, that directory needs to be created as part of running your app — another developer ran into problems trying to create the directories ahead of time. So, for your use case, this approach is unlikely to be practical, though with luck I am wrong and it proves useful to you.

> do I need to have root acces to read /mnt folders (except media_rw)?

In general, yes, though in practice the answer varies by device, Android OS version, etc.

Comment: No, my file is not in the External directories. It's supposed to be in a USB stick and the app should only work when the stick is plugged in.

Comment: @III.6: "It's supposed to be in a USB stick" -- `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()` all return a `File[]`. If that array has 2+ entries, the second and subsequent ones are on removable storage, such as your USB OTG drive. Those directories you can read and write to without permissions, using ordinary Java file I/O.

Comment: But it doesn't. On my phone each of them returns an array of size 1 and and all of them have the prefix `/storage/emulated/0/Android/`, while my stick is mounted in `/storage/USBstorage1`.

Comment: @III.6: Does the device recognize the drive, besides your advertised mount point? For example, do you have a notification for this drive, with an "Explore" action, that works?

Comment: Yes, it does. There's a notification titled "USB storage connected" and it says "Tap to remove USB storage safely". But no "Explore" option.

Update: Also tested on a Nexus 5, which shows a notification with "Explore" and "Eject" options. but still the arrays are of size 1.

Comment: @III.6: The more important point is whether you can browse that storage. On Android 6.0+ (and perhaps 5.x, I forget), there should be an "Explore" action on the notification that brings up an activity where you can browse the drive, copy files to external storage, etc.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. FX File Manager and LG's stock file manager find it too. But on Nexus 5, FX doesn't. though the "Explore" option in the notification works.

Comment: @III.6: If you are not getting 2+ items from `getExternalFilesDirs()` and kin on the Nexus 5 (and on the LG, if it is running Android 4.4+), I cannot explain that result.

Comment: So, what do I do? test it on other devices?

Comment: @III.6: "So, what do I do?" -- I don't really have much to suggest. Your overall use case (detect a special file on removable storage without user intervention) is not a use case that Android supports especially well. I would explore alternative solutions for whatever you are trying to achieve by this file-detection system.

Comment: It's not really in my hands. I'm just the guy who has to implement it. Thanks for you information anyway :)